# ASP.Net Razor Days between dates

Tags: asp.net, razor

I am working on a project and I need to calculate the days between date account created and current date.  my code works how ever it is not giving me just the days. This below code

```
@(item.AccountCreated.AddYears(1)-DateTime.Now)
```

gives me this result like this 330.06:53:24.6752284   when all I want to be displayed would be 330 is there a way to do this through Razor.

Issue now resolved by doing

```
@Convert.ToInt32(((item.AccountCreated.AddYears(1)-DateTime.Now).TotalDays))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
@((item.AccountCreated.AddYears(1)- DateTime.Now).TotalDays)
```

Comment: Thanks HokBong with your assistance I have now sorted it out by doing the following @Convert.ToInt32(((item.AccountCreated.AddYears(1)-DateTime.Now).TotalDays))